# Is there an input box for world rotation location?

Tags: coordinates

I only see transform location, rotation (Local).
How to influence world coordinate, by inputting number in pose mode?

Comment: Hello. Your question is a bit unclear. World coordinates start at (0,0,0) all from that is considered as a transformation.

Comment: But, you're right to ask. This is a convention in some way. World coordinates are defined by the transformations. By these transformations, object "acquires" their own coordinates in world space.

Comment: In N panel, there are tranform section with XYZ location, rotation and scale. There are fields where you can input numbers to influence for example the location of an object.
So that's what I meant with 'tranform'. 
But this location data is relative the the origin of the object itself. Not the world. 
If in edit mode I move the object, than 0,0,0 won't be the center of the world anymore. 
The question is, where/how can I see/edit the data of location,rotation that's relative to the world?

Comment: In edit mode, afaik, you can't. In edit mode vertices location is relative to the object transformations.Only way is to keep the object at (0,0,0) in object mode, then in edit place them in edit mode (if no transformation, coordinates are the same).

Comment: I would parent the edited object to an empty with the same origin, and rotate the empty to get a world rotation

Comment: Sorry I'm not being specific enough. What I need to know is on the Pose Mode. If I want to input the exact location relative to the world in Pose Mode, if that's possible. 
Because what's available now in my understanding, is input fields for local location (and rotation and scale)

Comment: @JuanFeju, I think you should rephrase your question entirely as it does not mention anything about pose mode or armature.

Answer (score 1):

You can access information about your model in any mode, by hitting 'N' bringing up the 'Object Data' tab.

I am guessing you are wanting to see your 'global rotation' value in the form of a 'degree'. Unfortunately there is no 'object' orientation visualizer, as the code that makes up a complex object full of vertices, edges, and angles. Can't really translate a number that you want.

However, if you have a bone attached to that object, there lies your data. From what I have observed, this data can only be accessed in 'Pose Mode', while having selected your bone of choice.

Inside the 'Object Data' tab, there is a tab listed 'item'. In that tab there is a rotation data sheet. Underneath that data, is a option menu called 'Quaternion(WXYZ)'. There is an option called 'Axis Angle'. Once you click on it, you can now see a visualized number of the rotation data of a bone.

Comment: If this is to your satisfaction, please accept this as the answer. Thanks